# Firebase Firestore security rule: Only allow collection group query if filtering by a specific field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'd like to add a Firestore security rule that allows a collection group query, but only if there's a where clause on the `id` field. In essence, I'm like to allow the user to retrieve the document only if s/he knows the `id`.

In other words, I'd like to allow this:

```
db.collectionGroup('widgets').where('id', '==', '123').get()
```

...but not this:

```
db.collectionGroup('widgets').get()
```

The security rule would look something like this:

```
match /{path=**}/widgets/{widgetId} {
  allow list: if request.query.keys().hasAny(['id']);
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to check the properties of the query filters.  All you have access to in the query is what you see in the [documentation for request.query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#query).  Rules that limit access to documents based on their contents are always expressed in terms of the documents that *would be matched* by the query.

You could restrict queries to one particular known id:

```
allow list: if request.resource.data.id == '123';
```

or a set of IDs, or an ID from another source (such as custom claims, or another document).

But if you want someone to only get a document using known "private" information that's specified in the query, that information will have to be in the document ID itself, not a field:

```
allow get;  // anyone can get a single document by ID, if they know that ID
// but do not allow read or list
```

This might require a change to your data model, or maybe a copy of data indexed by this other ID that you want to allow.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's possible to do what I want to do. I was hoping to be able to access the query fields in the security rule, but it doesn't look like that's possible. The access rule that I want to grant is: anyone with a known id is able to access that document. If the document was stored at the top level, that would be easy, as I'd just allow the `get` request, however, the document is nested inside a subcollection of another document and that path is unknown, hence the collection group query. It looks like I'll need to deploy a cloud function to do this.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible as far as I know. The `request.query` is a map of 3 properties namely `limit`, `offset` and `orderBy` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#query). That being said `request.query.keys()` should be a list like this:

```
["limit", "offset", "orderBy"]
```

This will never have a key `id` and your rule will return false always.

Comment: Yes, true. I did a debug output on `request.query.keys()` and this was the result:

`list_value {
  values {
    string_value: "allDescendants"
  }
  values {
    string_value: "ancestor"
  }
  values {
    string_value: "distinct"
  }
  values {
    string_value: "groupBy"
  }
  values {
    string_value: "kind"
  }
  values {
    string_value: "limit"
  }
  values {
    string_value: "offset"
  }
  values {
    string_value: "orderBy"
  }
  values {
    string_value: "selectOnlyKeys"
  }
}`